# XMPPPY unable to connect to the server

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd, xmpppy

I am using xmpppy python library to connect with XMPP server(ejabberd2) but unable to connect and actually don't have clarity on how to connect, authenticate and send a message to the server.

Please help me to make it working

If possible please provide some code snippet using XMPPPY.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out the solution with the help of a friend

It requires change the in XMPP ejabberd server config.
Change the line **{hosts, ["localhost"]}** with **{hosts, ["localhost", "server-domain", "server-ip-address"]}** in the ejabberd.cfg file.

Restart the server and create another user under new hosts with the server domain or server ip.

**Code snippet:**

```
import xmpp

ipaddress='<server-ip>'
user='<new-user>' #without @<server-ip>
passwd='<password>'

c = xmpp.Client(ipaddress)
c.connect((ipaddress,5222), secure=0)
c.auth(user,passwd,sasl=1)
c.sendInitPresence()
c.isConnected()
c.send(xmpp.protocol.Message('<jid of receiver user with @<domain> >',"hello world"))
```